# Share integer array across shared memory from Managed to Unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I wish to share an `integer array`, of a fixed size, across from a `Windows Service` in `C#`, to a code written in `unmanaged C++`. This will be across 2 processes, the `Windows Service` in `C#`, to another process in `C++`.

This transaction needs to be done once, and it is not a big array, just that it needs to be passed, across shared memory between the two.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? Perhaps with `memory mapped files`, but I am not certain how will the data be passed across.

**EDIT -**

I do not wish to use a `CLI` wrapper, or`P/INVOKE`(since I understand it is time expensive).

I will go ahead with memory mapping, but I am not sure how the data is to be `marshalled` and `unmarshalled` across the two.

Comment: Why not [use P/Invoke to pass the array to the unmanaged function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk9wyw21%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Trying to write Low latency code. From my understanding, P/Invoke costs time.

Comment: I think I will used Memory mapped file, but I am not sure how the data is to be Marshalled on the managed side, and then unmarshalled on the other.

Comment: You would normally only used memory mapped files to transfer data between two separate processes. You question doesn't make it clear whether you are in fact using two separate processes, or just want to make an in-proc call code in an unmanaged DLL. Which of those is it? Using an MMF to transfer data in-proc is likely to be slower than just using a P/Invoke call to transfer the array.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear. This will be across 2 processes. The `Service` in `c#`, to a process in `C++`.

Comment: In that case, yes: Just use an MMF and fill it with the data and perhaps use a named synchronization event (using EventWaitHandle in C# and CreateEvent() in Windows API) to signal when the MMF has been filled.

Comment: How would the data be placed in the file? Would there need to be any special handing for data across Managed - Unmanaged boundaries?

Comment: No, you just use `MemoryMappedViewAccessor.Write()` or `MemoryMappedViewAccessor.WriteArray()` to write the ints. It will be aligned between the processes. Have you read [the documentation for MMFs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? (You'd need to use the Windows API functions for the unmanaged code, of course.)

Comment: Yes, I meant if I write Integers from managed C#, to be read off memory by a C++ piece of code, do I need to worry about the sizes? I will be reading a chunk of memory from the mapped file. How do I cast it to an integer array in C++?

Comment: You just use the Windows API's `MapViewOfFile()` to get a void* to the block of data in the MMF and cast the void* to int*.

Comment: Right. Got it. Thank you. If you write it out as an answer, I shall mark it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the C# side you can use the [`MemoryMappedFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to access a memory mapped file.

On the Unmanaged side you can use the Windows API function [`CreateFileMapping()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open the mapped file, and then use [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a `void*` to the data in the file. You can then cast that `void*` to an `int*` to access the data as an array of ints.

You might also want to use a named synchronization event (using [`EventWaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C# and [`CreateEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows API) to signal when the MMF has been filled.

Answer (score 1):

There are different way to achieve this -

1. Write a small CLI wrapper layer.
2. Use shared resource. e.g. write in a file form c# and then read in c++

Comment: I do not wish to write a CLI wrapper. For the second option, could you elaborate that a bit?

Comment: @user1173240 write your array in a text file using C# and then read that file using c++. e.g. you can store your array as comma separated `int` and then use comma as delimiter to separate it while reading in c++

Comment: OK, I understand the shared resource. But the data is sensitive and cannot be written to a resource like a text file.

Comment: if data is sensitive you may use encryption before writing and same decryption before reading.